# Best way to inverse if-else based on a condition

Tags: c#, if-statement

I wanted an `if-else` clause to behave based on an input that would leave the statements as is, or switch statements between if and else.

To be specific, I am parsing an html tag `country` and `uncountry`.  Based on its attribute, which lists the countries for the tag, I will be able to decide whether to skip the inner content or not.  `country` tag will copy inner content, while `uncountry` does the opposite.  The `if (parseCountry)` is to parse `country` tag, and the else for `uncountry` tag.

For example:

```
                if (parseCountry)
                {
                    if (inCountryList)
                    {
                        do A;
                        do B;
                    }
                    else if (notInCountryList)
                        do C;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (inCountryList)
                        do C;
                    else if (notInCountryList)
                    {
                        do A;
                        do B;
                    }
                }
```

What is the best way to simplify the if-else statements above?  Thanks.

Comment: `if (!condition)` probably?

Comment: That is the exact effect i wanted.  However, how do you convert an input into a '!' operator?

Comment: Which language? What kind of input?

Comment: Your first code will automatically do both things you want. If condition, then A and B are done; otherwise, C is done. If not condition, C is done, A and B are not. You're overthinking it, apparently.

Comment: C#, boolean or string input is fine.

Comment: Hi Clay, I hope to use the input in my conditional statement, if possible.

Comment: What do you mean by "merge"?

Comment: I don't understand this question. Assuming `condition` is already exactly "the reverse" of `reverse` (i.e. `condition == !reverse` is always true), then your two pseudo-code examples appear identical in function to me. Please provide a good [mcve] that shows clearly what you are doing, and provide a precise explanation of what that code does and how that's different from what you want it to do.

Comment: Hi Peter, edited to explain the problem better.

Comment: This is c#, this ain't ruby.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is what you're looking for:

```
if (parseCountry == inCountryList)
{
    do A;
    do B;
}
else
{
    do C;
}
```

The condition is fulfilled when both booleans have the same value: either both are `True` or both are `False`.

Comment: This answer would be a good one if you had incorporated the OP's `notInCountryList` variable as well.

Comment: Sorry, this won't do.  I am parsing tags in an html string.  One of those tags is a <country> tag.  And in the country tag, I need to know if my current country is in the list <country:CA;GB;>   If my current country is in the list, I will show the inner content.  If not, I will hide the inner content.

Answer (score 1):

For convenience, I'm going to use `do AB;` to reflect your two-statement block.

To summarize the logic you want to implement: if `parseCountry` and `inCountryList` both have the same value, execute `do AB;`, otherwise execute `do C;`, but with the provision that in either case, the `!inCountryList` case should be executed only if `notInCountryList` is itself `true`.

Written out in C#(-ish) code, that would look something like this:

```
if (inCountryList || notInCountryList)
{
    if (parseCountry == inCountryList)
    {
        do A;
        do B;
    }
    else
    {
        do C;
    }
}
```

Or put another way: if neither `inCountryList` or `notInCountryList` are true, do nothing. Otherwise, execute the code according to whether `parseCountry` is equal to `inCountryList`. This is consistent with the implementation you've shown in your question.